# identical variables declared 'extern' in multiple translation units can be unique entities?

Tags: gcc, linker, declaration, extern

According to the C99 standard:

```
In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each
declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object or
function.
```

Now I am not a native English speaker, but to me this essentially means that if I have
`extern int var;` in two translation units, the linker will link them together so that both declarations will end up linking to the same object when such is defined anywhere.

If this is true, then why if I purposely change the type of one of the declarations the compiler/linker does not produce a diagnostic that the types are conflicting, but it does so if the two extern declarations are declared in the same translation unit?

It even allows me to define the variable in the same translation unit:

- TU1:

---

```
extern int var;
```

---

- TU2:

---

```
extern float var;
float var = 2.5;
```

But if I also define var in TU1, the linker basically crashes, without providing any diagnostic again. The compilation flags are:

`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror=shadow -std=c99`

My question can be wrapped up by asking why does GCC behave like that (misdiagnosing on both occasions) and what should be the ideal, standard-conforming treatment for a code like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why if I purposely change the type of one of the declarations the compiler/linker does not produce a diagnostic that the types are conflicting,

The types of symbols are lost when linking. Linker only sees names of symbols. And matches the names.

> why

It's 2022 nowadays. LTO and C++ modules were introduced for a reason, and we have many more sophisticated programming languages. C is a 50 years old language. There was not enough computer power and man power when C programming language and linker were invented to let it be aware of symbol types. It was just not implemented.

Note that the document you are reading does not *require* a diagnostic, in the case this rule is broken. In case the rule is broken, you get "undefined behavior". Undefined behavior means there is *no requirement* on what will happen, you may get a diagnostic, or spawn nasal demons. You can't "expect" a diagnostic. See [wikipedia undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) .

Also note that you are reading C99, which is 20 years old. Consider [C11](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html), or C23.

> it does so if the two extern declarations are declared in the same translation unit?

Because the *compiler* sees the whole translation unit when compiling, it sees the symbol conflict and *is able* to say something about it. Or maybe in other words, because [5.1.1.3p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.1.1.3p1) requires that a diagnostic is issued in such case.

> what should be the ideal, standard-conforming treatment for a code like this?

Complete ignore such case. Assume it will never happen.

It is the other way round. A standard-conforming compiler is required to compile standard-conforming programs. There is no requirements on the result of compilation of any other programs. If you feed a program with undefined behavior to any conforming compiler, anything is allowed to happen. Compilers may assume the programmer will never write a program with undefined behavior, so they can completely ignore that such a case will ever happen. It is programmers fault that he has written invalid program and that programmer should fix it.

Comment: Thank you!! It is a relief that it wasn't me misinterpreting the standard specification draft. I am writing a complete C99-compatible C interpreter in GCC flavor, and the linkage phase is something completely different, so I had to know what is the correct way to handle this :) Since object integrity is preserved, I will issue an error after all.